# Cannot erase border from bootstrap drop down menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, drop-down-menu, border

So I use [this Bootstrap structure](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/) on my own project.

When the window gets smaller, and the drop down menu is collapsed , as you can see in the image, there is a small border there that will not go away (inside black circle).

At first it was white, so I overwrite the css style and change its color to match the background. But this small border of slightly different color will not go away. I try setting `border-style: none;` for `#navbar`, nothing. I set

```
*{
  border-style: none;
}
```

for the whole page and still this border will not go away.

How do I make it go away? Maybe its part of the animation? Because when the drop down menu is up, it goes away. Please help me

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this css

```
.navbar-collapse {
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work. Just kidding. It worked right away. I am so excited, I wish i could write in all caps. This little thingy was haunting me for hours. Thank you man. You saved me. Also, change `border: 0:` to `border: 0;` in your code.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I myself faced that issue long ago, so could help you instantly. :)